# Is "ut ostendo sursum" an accurate Latin translation of "keep showing up"?

Tags: translation-check, english-to-latin-translation

I'm hoping someone can help with confirming a translation, or suggesting an alternative, of “keep showing up” into Latin. Google translate and a few other online translators have suggested *ut ostendo sursum*. Advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Machine translation is notoriously bad for Latin.

> *ut ostendo sursum*
>
> 'while I reveal [something] on high'

A grammatical and sensible translation:

> *semper adesto*
>
> 'always be present'

This is *present* meaning *in attendance,* not in the modern spiritual sense.

Comment: Awesome  Thank you so much. I had tried so many variants and looked at root words but felt that something may have been lost in translation. I appreciate your response!

Comment: @user2778 All good. Keep in mind that this is a singular imperative (an order addressed to one person). If you want to address a group, it would be *semper adeste.*